# selecting multiple checkbox on form load using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a var in javascript say var a = "1:2:3' which basically has the values of a previously selected multi checkbox group.
    Now what I'm trying to do is to populate a new checkbox with these values, basically selecting options 1,2 and 3.
    I'm trying something but w/o any success.
    Any suggestions?

Note: I cannot update the html, as I have no access to it, and it has no id attribute!!

```
Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/2fyp6unp/2/
```

Comment: Always put your code in your question please. And FYI, looking at your fiddle, IDs **must** be unique. And what's `selectmenu()`?

Comment: Wait, so you want a new input element of checkbox type with value "1, 2, and 3?"

Comment: @j08691: That's jQuery UI's fancy dropdown.

Comment: @Purag - the the fiddle and question would probably benefit from jQueryUI...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this(worked when I tried) :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="bType[]" id="b1" value="1">&nbsp;ONE<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="bType[]" id="b2" value="2">&nbsp;TWO<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="bType[]" id="b3" value="3">&nbsp;THREE<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="bType[]" id="b4" value="4">&nbsp;FOUR<br>
```

Then in javascript I wrote something like this :

```
var a = "1:2:3";

var a_split=a.split(":");

$('input[name="bType[]"]').each(function() {
        var chkbox = $(this).val();
               for (var i=0; i < a_split.length; i++) 
               {
                if(a_split[i]==chkbox)
                {
                    $(this).prop('checked', true);
                }
              }
            });
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Raghavendra. I used your solution and just removed the ids and [] from name attribute and jquery. It works!!

Comment: You are welcome! Let me edit my answer and please edit the question to include that the html can not be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would solve this issue.  Since you should have unique id's for your HTML inputs, you can append the value to the id and thus be able to select them directly (if you like, you can also use name, data prop, etc.).

If you don't have the ability to update your HTML, you'll need to set up a separate loop to iterate through the inputs, check the value, then set the 'checked' prop accordingly.

In terms of JS, first off, you'll need to convert your var a input to a data structure more suitable in JS like an array.  Afterwords, you can iterate through the array and set the 'checked' property if there's a match.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2fyp6unp/3/

Updated HTML with unique ID's:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="bType" id="bType1" value="1">&nbsp;ONE
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="bType" id="bType2" value="2">&nbsp;TWO
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="bType" id="bType3" value="3">&nbsp;THREE
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="bType" id="bType4" value="4">&nbsp;FOUR
<br>
```

JS:

```
var a = "1:2:3";
var b = a.split(":"); // change a to array, split on ':'

for (var i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
    $('#bType' + b[i]).prop('checked', true); // set values based on id
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solutions Will and Raghavendra..I do not have access to html, so I cannot change it. View source does not show me an id attribute, it only has name.